# Bonferroni adjustment method in p.adjust

Tags: r, statistics, bonferroni

I'm confused with the help of p.adjust. According to it, "The adjustment methods include the Bonferroni correction ("bonferroni") in which the p-values are multiplied by the number of comparisons," but I was under the impression that it should be divided instead of multiplied. See, for example, the Wikipedia entry on this topic:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The alpha level is divided by the number of comparisons. That's equivalent to multiplying the p-values by the number of comparisons

Comment: You can either keep `alpha = 0.05`, multiply the p-values by `m`, and compare the multiplied p to alpha. Or you can set `alpha = 0.05 / m`, and compare the original p-values to the adjusted alpha. The two approaches are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks guys! both comments clarify my confusion.